# Laravel Multi Auth using Middle ware

Tags: php, laravel, routes, middleware

I have created an app with user_type(stored in table) as admin,user,super_admin and Created 2 middle wares such as Admin and super Admin. 
When i try to login as user and access a function which is set to admin it redirects correctly to home page, when admin tries to access its accessing correctly, but when super admin tries to access the same function which is assigned to admin its not accessing where i have set correct param and routing for super admin same as admin, Please take a look below of my code

This is my admin-middle ware:

```html
public function handle($request, Closure $next, $guard = 'admin')
    {

        if (Auth::user()->user_type =='admin') {
            return $next($request);
        } else {
             return redirect('home')->with('error','You have not admin access');
        }
    }
```

This is my super-admin middle-ware:

```html
public function handle($request, Closure $next, $guard = 'super_admin') {

    if (Auth::user()->user_type =='super_admin') {
        return $next($request);
    } else {
         return redirect('home')->with('error','You have not admin access');
    }
}
```

This is my routing web.php

```html
Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@index')->name('home');

    Route::get('/contact', 'StudentController@create')->name('contact');

    //User Activate

    Route::group(['middleware' => ['admin'], 'namespace' => 'Admin', 'prefix' => 'admin'], function(){
     Route::resource('/admin', 'AdminController');
     Route::get('/get-users/', 'AdminController@getUsers');
     Route::get('/get-cfs/', 'AdminController@getCfs');
     Route::get('/random-user/', 'AdminController@randomUser');
     //Route::resource('/student', 'StudentController');
    });

    Route::group(['middleware' => ['superadmin'], 'namespace' => 'SuperAdmin', 'prefix' => 'superadmin'], function(){
     Route::resource('/superAdmin', 'SuperAdminController');
     Route::get('/get-users/', 'AdminController@getUsers');
     Route::get('/get-cfs/', 'AdminController@getCfs');
     Route::get('/random-user/', 'AdminController@randomUser');
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You did not specify that super admin has all the privileges that and admin has. You are just specifying two guards `super_admin` and `admin`. But how can laravel know that `super_admin` has all the privileges that an `admin` has ? You should implement this or you can simple do this in your `admin` middleware.

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next, $guard = 'admin')
{
    if (Auth::user()->user_type =='super_admin' || Auth::user()->user_type =='admin') {
        return $next($request);
    } else {
         return redirect('home')->with('error','You have not admin access');
    }
}
```

Comment: By doing this can i restrict some functions ? i.e, can i differentiate some functions between admin and super admin ?